# Meaning of “foiled rail sabotage bid”

Tags: meaning

I found these words in [The Hindu](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/Arrested-Maoist-considered-a-key-catch/article16985652.ece) and search their meaning but not able to find exact meaning:

> The recent encounter killing of two Maoists in Wayanad in Kerala is suspected to have been the trigger for the **foiled rail sabotage bid**.

I found meaning of these words like below

- *foiled* – prevent (something considered wrong or undesirable) from succeeding.
- *sabotage* – deliberately destroy, damage, or obstruct (something), especially for political or military advantage.

Can anyone please tell me the what this sentence tells us?

Comment: It means a bid that was foiled, a bid to sabotage the rail.  I suspect you are confused by an adjective followed by three nouns in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The killing is thought to have provoked a bid (attempt) to sabotage (damage) a railway. The attempt was unsuccessful (foiled).